# Google Cloud SQL rejecting my query

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-sql

I've been running a Django application on my local machine and am trying to push it to appengine. One of the queries I was making before that never caused any trouble was:

```
ALTER TABLE Records ADD COLUMN Id
```

but when I try to execute this query on Cloud SQL, I get this error:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for Alter table is

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype
```

You forgot to specify the datatype for `Id`

Something like

```
ALTER TABLE Records ADD COLUMN Id INT
```